# How to use LispWorks' fast-directory-files with fdf-handle-* functions?

Tags: common-lisp, filepath, lispworks

LispWorks' `fast-directory-files` with `fdf-handle-*` functions seem very promising. The [Fast access to files in a directory](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/LW/html/lw-219.htm) page in the LispWorks manual says,

> *fast-directory-files* gives a faster way to access files than *directory*, especially in situations when you need to filter based on simple features such as size and access time, or filter based on the name in a more complex way than *directory* can.

I am trying to understand how they can be used, but I am meeting with a bit of opacity in documentation, beside the fact I am quite new to Common Lisp.

Let's say as an example, one would wish to fetch the file size of a file, using `fdf-handle-size`. The [detailed manual page](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/LW/html/lw-599.htm) offers no examples and the text seems a bit terse. For example,

> The *fdf-handle* can be accessed by the following readers. Functions named in parentheses would return the same value when called on the full path of the file:
>
> **fdf-handle-size** returns the size of the file in bytes.
>
> [etc.]

*Notes* says,

> The *fdf-handle* can be used only within the dynamic scope of the callback to which it was passed.

By trial and error I got to this point (of course wrong):

```
CL-USER 1 > (let (file-size)
  (fast-directory-files "/temp/a.txt"
                        #'(lambda (path handle)
                           (push (fdf-handle-size handle) file-size))))
("save.lisp" "a.txt" "a.lisp")
```

How could one get the file size for `/temp/a.txt`? More importantly, how one is supposed to use LispWorks' `fast-directory-files` with `fdf-handle-*` functions in general?

Comment: In your snippet you are not displaying the results of the callback, you are seeing the results of fast-directory-files which returns the list of files for which there is a result. Print out file-size and see what’s in there

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add `file-size` before the last parentheses. I get `(1119 0 1662)`, that is the sizes of the three files there. How to filter only one file? Is that the idiomatic way to deal with those functions? I really had to try by trail and error to arrive there, I am not sure that way is proper?

Comment: @DavidHodge If you could make your comment into an answer, I could vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Snippet above does not return the output of the callback. Hence

```
(let (file-size)
  (fast-directory-files "/temp/a.txt"
                        #'(lambda (path handle)
                           (push (fdf-handle-size handle) file-size)))
  file-size)
```

Will result in a list of file sizes for all files in the directory.

Note also that fast-directory-files accepts a *dir-pathname* - the intention is to deal with all files in a directory hence the a.txt is ignored.

If you just need the size of a single file - open it and use file-length (paying attention to the element size of course).

Comment: Thank you, also for the additional detail on working on a single file.